# React setState {} not setting variable

Tags: reactjs, object, authentication, setstate

I have the following code for a main view and user login:

```
export class MainView extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            array: [],        
            user: null,
            userData: {},    
        };
    }

    setUserData(user) {

        if (user) {
            this.setState({ userData: user.user });
            console.log(user.user);
            console.log (userData); /* errors in console */
        } else {
            console.log('userData not set');
        }

   }


   onLoggedIn(authData) {

       this.setState({ user: authData.user.Username });

       /* setting localstorage key:item */

       // console.log(authData);

       localStorage.setItem('token', authData.token);

       localStorage.setItem('user', authData.user.Username);

       this.getArrayObjects(authData.token);

       this.setUserData(authData);

   }
```

using Passport to get the auth data and token. I don't get why it will log **user.user** in the setUserData function but will log an "undefined" error for the **userData** variable in the same function. Any ideas?

Comment: Because there's no variable called `userData` in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an undefined variable.

`userData` is present inside the state.

So you should access it with `this.state.userData`.

But even it you write `console.log(userData);`, it will print `{}` because in React, `setState` is `asynchronous`. Meaning, the state is not updated immediately.

If you want to check whether state has been update or not, check it like this.

```
this.setState({ userData: user.user }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.userData);
});
```

The, second parameter to `setState` is a function that is called once `state` is successfully updated. So, inside there you can see the value in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the state directly as a var. You need to access the state, and the the properties:

```
console.log(state.userData);
```

Also, in your code, when you print state.userData, probably you will see the old value, since the setState is an async function.